# extracting json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some json from a remote server and the results are returned like this:

```
[{"item1":"tag1","a1":"b1"},{"item2":"tag2","a2":"b2"}]
```

How would I get the value of a1 and a2?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its Javascript.

Comment: Yes, i'm using  $.get(); to get the json.

Comment: Okay; that makes a difference as well. Please try to include this highly-relevant information up-front. BTW, what you are showing is not valid JSON. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that Javascript could be put inside the jQuery, am I wrong to think that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) if the data is still in string form:

```
var rawData = '[{"item1":"tag1","a1":"b1"},{"item2":"tag2","a2":"b2"}]';
var parsed = JSON.parse(rawData);
console.log(parsed[0].a1); // logs "b1"
console.log(parsed[1].a2); // logs "b2"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/WK9gz/

---

Since you're using jQuery, swap out `$.get()` for `$.getJSON()` and jQuery will automagically parse the JSON for you. Inside of the `success` callback, you'll have a normal JavaScript object to work with — no parsing required.

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/foo/bar/baz', function (data)
{
    console.log(data[0].a1); // logs "b1"
    console.log(data[1].a2); // logs "b2"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.