# How to extract array index 0 from json array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following JSON:

```
[[{"id":37,"address1":"2 town","address2":"apt 111","city":"sanjose","state":"CA","zip":"97878"},{"id":37,"address1":"2 town","address2":"apt 111","city":"sanjose","state":"CA","zip":"97878"}]]
```

I need to extract only this part of JSON:

```
[{"id":37,"address1":"2 town","address2":"apt 111","city":"sanjose","state":"CA","zip":"97878"},{"id":37,"address1":"2 town","address2":"apt 111","city":"sanjose","state":"CA","zip":"97878"}]
```

basically i need to extract only array of index[0].

Please can anyone help and provide a solution on how to extract json data in the above example in JavaScript

Thanks

Comment: `arr[0]` will give you the part of JSON that you need. Why do you have an array inside an array ?

Comment: Did you follow this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988726/extracting-json-data

Comment: @adeneo `arr[0][0]` quick and sweet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (assuming your JSON is in a string):

```
var a = JSON.parse('[[{"id":37,"address1":"2 town","address2":"apt 111","city":"sanjose","state":"CA","zip":"97878"},{"id":37,"address1":"2 town","address2":"apt 111","city":"sanjose","state":"CA","zip":"97878"}]]');

var result = a[0];
```

Hope it can help :)